# Removing objects of different types from the stage in AS3, using one method only

Tags: actionscript-3, syntax, removechild

I am making a space invader kind of game in ActionScript3 and I have created a method to remove bullets from the stage:

```
private function removeBullet(bb:Bullet = null):void {

    var leng:uint = bulletVector.length;
    if (bb)
    {
        for (var i:uint = 0; i < leng; i++)
        {
            if (bulletVector[i] == bb) 
            {
                bulletVector.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }                   
        }

        // Remove bullet from the Display List
        removeChild(bb);

        // Return the bullet to its object pool
        bulletPool.returnObject(bb);    

    } else {

        // Remove all existing bullets currently on screen
        for (var j:uint = 0; j < leng; j++)
        {
            var bullet:Bullet = bulletVector[j];
            removeChild(bullet);
            bulletPool.returnObject(bullet);
        }
        bulletVector.splice(0, leng);   
    }
}
```

*bulletVector* is a Vector that contains all the bullets that are currently displayed and *bulletPool* is an object pool class to return bullets to when they're not used on the stage anymore. If no argument is passed to the method, the method removes ALL the bullets on screen.

Now, I have an **identical** method to remove enemies from the screen:

```
private function removeEnemy(ee:Enemy = null):void {

    var leng:uint = enemyVector.length;
    if (ee)
    {
        for (var i:uint = 0; i < leng; i++)
        {
            if (enemyVector[i] == ee) 
            {
                enemyVector.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }               
        }

        // Remove enemy from the Display List
        removeChild(ee);

        // Return the enemy to its object pool
        enemyPool.returnObject(ee); 

    } else {

        // Remove all existing enemies currently on screen
        for (var j:uint = 0; j < leng; j++)
        {
            var enemy:Enemy = enemyVector[j];
            removeChild(enemy);
            enemyPool.returnObject(enemy);
        }
        enemyVector.splice(0, leng);    
    }
}
```

Both 'bullets' and 'enemies' are classes that extend the Sprite class. My question is: is it possible to merge these two methods into one that handles both bullets AND enemies, depending on which one is passed as an argument?

[EDIT]
What I have in mind is something like this: (pseudocode)

```
if (ee is Bullet) 
{ 
    var s:String = "bullet" 
} else if (ee is Enemy) 
{ 
    var s:String = "enemy" 
} 

eval[s+"Vector"].splice(i, 1); 
eval[s+"Pool"].returnObject(ee);
```

[/EDIT]

In other words, is there a syntax that allows to access Vectors and/or Classes (the object pools) without having to hardcode their name into the method?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this might work for you...

```
private function removeItem(ee:* = null):void {

if (ee) {
//ee has a value

if (ee is Bullet) {
//remove bullet

} else if (ee is Enemy) {
//remove Enemy

}

} else {

//ee is null so remove all bullets and emenies

}
}
```

Comment: Actually this is much clever than what I suggest. Only that you'd need to edit the method as you add new types.

Comment: When ee is null you don't really know if you're meant to remove all bullets or all enemies.
I suggest having a separate removeAll method, as it will be safer.

Comment: Now that I think of it... what would the implementation of //remove Enemy and // remove Bullet be like? I guess they would two almost identical blocks of code...

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, yes, this is a clever way to do it. 

I was wondering though if it was somehow possible to call a Vector (bulletVector) or a Class (bulletPool) selectively using something like this (pseudocode):

`if (ee is Bullet) {
    var s:String = "bullet"
} else if (ee is Enemy) {
    var s:String = "enemy"
}

eval[s+"Vector"].splice(i, 1);
eval[s+"Pool"].returnObject(ee); `


In a sort of old ActionScript fashion.

Comment: @JulianG Yes, that's what I was thinking, instead of using two almost identical blocks of code in the same method (which is a bit like having two separate methods in the end), I was hoping I could manipulate Vectors (or Arrays) and Classes dinamically (see the pseudocode example above).

Comment: Ok, what you're doing there is using soft typing. By evaluating something + "Vector" you get a reference to the Vector instance without specifying its type. You can achieve the same soft-typing without using eval (which is scary).

For instance declare a function like this: function removeItem( list:*, item:Sprite, pool:* ):void

Now the argument list is of type * which is anything, so you can pass an instance of Vector.<Bullet> or Vector.<Enemy> and you won't get compile-time errors. And you can call list.splice(...)

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer: Use Array instead of Vector for the lists of enemies and bullets.**

Create a method that takes 3 arguments: a list:Array and an item:Sprite, and a pool:Array then remove the item from the specified Array, instead of 'hardcoding' the instance and ending up with two identical methods.

```
/**
 * Removes item from specified list
 * @param   list
 * @param   item
 */
public function removeItem( list:Array, item:Sprite, pool:Array ):void
{
    // implement here
}
```

**Long Answer:**

It's tricky because you're using Vectors.

My first impulse was to create a generic function taking 2 arguments, a list and an item:  (let's ignore the pool for now)

```
/**
 * Removes item from specified list
 * @param   list
 * @param   item
 */
public function removeItem( list:Vector.<Sprite>, item:Sprite ):void
{
    // implement here
}
```

But I'm guessing your list of bullets is of type Vector. and your list enemies is of type Vector., right?

So even if both Bullet and Enemy extend Sprite, if you were to call this method using an instance of Vector., for instance:

```
var list:Vector.<Bullet>;
var item:Bullet; // extends Sprite
removeItem( list, item );
```

This wouldn't compile. You'd get:

```
Error: Implicit coercion of a value of type __AS3__.vec:Vector.<Bullet> to an unrelated type __AS3__.vec:Vector.<flash.display:Sprite>.
```

**On a separate note**

Your removeItem method seems to be doing two things. Removing a specified item and/or removing all items. I would keep these separate for safety and clarity. Each method should perform only one thing.

Also, with this setup, if at runtime your reference to an item is accidentally null, you'll end up removing all items from the list. Probably not what you wanted.

I would declare two functions:

```
function removeItem(...)

function removeAllItems(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Julian, and yes you're right about splitting the remove method in 2 different ones, as a matter of fact other, slightly different, methods that remove other kind of objects in the game do have separate functions for 'one' and 'all' objects. So that's definitely something I have to do.

Answer (score 0):

On second thought, I would now favour soft-typing over using Arrays, because it would not force you to change the rest of your application (e.g. you can keep your Vectors)

```
public function removeItem(list:*, pool:ObjectPool, item:Sprite):void
{
    // remove item from specified list
    var indx:int = list.indexOf(item);
    if (indx >= 0) 
    {
        list.splice(indx, 1);
    }
    // remove display object from display list
    if (this.contains(item))
    {
        this.removeChild(item);
    }           
    // return itemitem to specified pool
    pool.returnObject(item);
}
```

Note how you don't need to iterate the Vector to find out which index to remove (splice). You can use the indexOf method instead.

Comment: In my example all pools are instances of or inherit from an ObjectPool class, that I assume have a returnObject method, right?

Comment: Yes, objectPool is a class (this class: [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS948100b6829bd5a6-19cd3c2412513c24bce-8000.html) to be precise).

I like the solution you posted, very elegant. The way I see it, the advantage of the solution posted by @crooksy88 is that I can pass just one argument to the method and the method call itself looks tidier (i.e. remove(bullet), as opposed to remove(bullerVector, bulletPool, bullet)), whereas the advantage of your solution is that the actual code within the method is a lot shorter and unified - and therefore easier to mantain. Thanks again!